# wordpress root dir

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354633/wordpress-root-directory)

I need to write a file in the root directory on a wordpress installation.  This need to be in the same place as the wp-config.php file.

But i need a way to call the root url.

Is there a wp_root_dir() like function

Comment: On the server side (`C:/www/wordpress`) or on the web address side (`www.example.com/wordpress/`)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want **root url** or **root dir**?

Given that you're putting this file into the root of your wordpress I assume its not a plugin or something like that.

Here is how to get the **root url**

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>
```

Otherwise if you want the path (to `include()` for instance) its perfectly reasonable to just do:

`../../../file-in-root.php -> as many ../s as you need to go back directories`

I do this all the time. If you think your directory structure may change a lot, you can just put the whole path to the file e.g.

`/home/w/o/wordpress/web/public_html/file-in-root.php`

If you're creating a plugin and you don't know the path to the file then obviously it would be different, but there are wordpress functions for that. However as you're using root I guess this is just for your own server/website configuration and this will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean on the client side (`http://www.myreallyawesomewebsitethatuseseordpress.com/blog/wordpress/`), you can use `get_bloginfo('url')`. This will return the url which wordpress is installed.

If you mean on the server side, you can use the `ABSPATH` variable.

Usage:

Client side:

```
<?php
    echo "You are using this site. Wordpress is on" . get_bloginfo('url');
?>
```

Server side:

```
<?php
    echo "On the server, Wordpress is installed on" . ABSPATH;
?>
```