# Wordpress - Get root directory?

Tags: wordpress

How can I get the root directory of my site? I want to use it as the `src` for `<img>`.

For example If I install the wordpress on `www.mysite.com/blog/`, the root is `/blog`.

But If I install it to `www.mysite.com/test/blog`, the root is `/test/blog`.

I tried to use the snippet from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354633/wordpress-root-directory), but it returns the whole path as seen in FTP. So instead of returning just `/blog`, it returns `/home/public_html/blog` which won't work if used as `src` in image tag.

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use `site_url()` (eventually with `echo`) to get absolute path with server name and directory. Also, have a look at [wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories) about similar functions & what they provide.

Comment: Wow `site_url()` does the trick. Though, it gives the full path like `http://mysite.com/blog`. But I guess it's okay.

Answer (score 7):

You may have better luck over at the [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site :)

And this suggestion to use `ABSPATH` didn't help on that thread? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356467/413254

Comment: Never knew that site exist. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, they've popped up all over the place for all sorts of topics. Definitely don't blame you. And no worries. Hope that helps.

Comment: I just tried the `ABSPATH` and it also returned the full path like `/home/public_html/blog`

Answer (score 2):

site_url() return the path with http, in some cases, it is not allowed if the server turns off url inclusion. You can use the function below to get the root path of wordpress installation folder:

```
function get_wp_installation()
{
    $full_path = getcwd();
    $ar = explode("wp-", $full_path);
    return $ar[0];
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just reproducing ABSPATH?