# How to make sure relative URL works when site is not on root domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just tried installing my theme on another WP install that lies in a subdirectory of the domain. I never really thought too hard about subdirectories, but it does happen so I know I need to change it. Absolute URLS aren't feasible since I plan on distributing the theme.

The catch here is that the URL needs to work inside of an array more specifically with some themes settings. Here is how they look.

```
function mytheme_get_theme_mods() {
$defaults = array(
'mytheme_header_logo'                => '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/logo.png',
'mytheme_footer_logo'                => '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/footerlogo.png',
'mytheme_middle_image'                => '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/middleimg.png'

);

return $defaults;
```

}

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2356467/452233

Comment: you really should be using `get_template_directory_uri()` or `get stylesheet directory()` ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory )

Comment: If I could downvote comments I would downvote ultranaut's comment. You should use `get stylesheet directory()` and not `ABSPATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     function mytheme_get_theme_mods() {
 $defaults = array(
'mytheme_header_logo'                => get_theme_root_uri().'/mytheme/img/logo.png',
'mytheme_footer_logo'                => get_theme_root_uri().'/mytheme/img/footerlogo.png',
'mytheme_middle_image'                => get_theme_root_uri().'/mytheme/img/middleimg.png'

);

return $defaults;
}
```

if you who like to look at the array's output place 'print_r($defaults);' underneath the return and then call the function in index.php and it will print the exact urls where it looking for the images.