# 404 file not found when requiring PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this PHP file which has an Ajax call of a file called, let's say test.php. This test.php requires two files, this is how they're called:

```
require('../folder1/folder2/header.php');
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

So, if I remove the second line of code, it works just fine, but as soon as I add that second line it no longer works, the Network tab in console gives me 404.

The wordpress file and the folder1 are in the same directory.

Comment: Should be `require('../wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: My bad, it actually is require('../wp-blog-header.php'); in the original.

Comment: can you give me `dirname(__FILE__);` and turn on error_reporting - `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: dirname gives me `/home/mojbrlog/public_html/esportshr/sc2/elo_league_v2.0` The `sc2` folder is where the wordpress file is in. And there are no errors reported.

Comment: you can add a `exit;` in the top of your `wp-blog-header.php` so see if still 404.

I think the require path is not the problem. 404 response is given by `wp-blog-header.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you going wrong way of AJAX in wordpress. Try following code not need include any file.In functions.php file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_YOUR-FUNCTION','YOUR-FUNCTION');
add_action('wp_ajax_YOUR-FUNCTION','YOUR-FUNCTION');

function YOUR-FUNCTION(){
   //  YOUR CODE
   die();
}
```

and client side your ajax call should following:

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : ajaxurl,
    data : { action :'YOUR-FUNCTION',var1:your-val,var2:your-val},
    success:function(data){
        // your success call
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**First**, Don't use relative path(s).
Check out these Questions, they're described nicely in terms of Paths.

- [WordPress issue causing massive error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490445/wordpress-issue-causing-massive-error-logs/24490800#24490800)
- [Retrieve WordPress root directory path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354633/wordpress-root-directory)

**Second**, Don't use `wp-blog-header.php` just like that. If you really want Wordpress Environment to work inside your test.php file, Then it'll be better if you either write code as a ***Plugin*** or write your code in ***function.php***.

***Reference Links***

- http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
- [Using AJAX in a WordPress plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin)

**Third**, `wp-blog-header.php` should be called before any file you are requiring in your code. So that way Wordpress environment loads into that file as well. Otherwise, Wordpress functions will not work properly.

Check `index.php` inside Wordpress root folder. `wp-blog-header.php` is the first file required to load Wordpress Environment.

**index.php** (At Wordpress Root Folder)

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Comment: @ downvoter. Please mention the reason of downvote. Please do not downvote just to keep answer lower in rank.

Answer (score 1):

If you're receiving a `404` error it means that is not exactly a php error that is ocurring. One of this files (probably `wp-blog-header.php`) are trying to redirect you to another page that is no longer available (e.g: this scripts are redirecting you using an `header('Location: ...')` to a page that is not available).

Check the contents of the files and look for a redirection of this type. An inclusion error do not brings to you a `404` alert, it should brings a `FATAL ERROR`.

**Additionaly...**

Always when you use `require()` function, try to use absolute paths. Relative paths causes a lot of problems when you're using a third party code.
Use

```
require(__DIR__.'/../wp-blog-header.php');
```

instead of

```
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: o.O you just added path issue after my answer. Anyways, nice update. :)

Comment: @AbhineetVerma, yes!!! I didnt know if i should make a citation so i didnt. But the objective was to improve the knowledge behind the answer, because even better then show an error to the programmer is prevent him to do it again. Thanks for your comment. ;)