# Wordpress - Include_once root files

Tags: php, wordpress, include-once

I'm trying to include some `.php` files in the `header.php` of my Wordpress Site.

Here is my schema:

```
Root/
    |_ includes
        |_ db_connect.php
        |_ functions.php
        |_ var_list.php
    |_ wp-includes
    |_ wp-content
        |_ themes
            |_ NameTheme
                |_ header.php
    |_ wp-admin
```

I need to include this lines on my `header.php`

```
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
include_once 'includes/var_list.php';

sec_session_start(); // function to start session, placed in functions.php
```

---

What I tryed:

1. With **`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`**
2. With **`dirname(_FILE_)`**
3. With **`ABSPATH`** // this are define on my `wp-config.php`
4. With **`home_url`**
5. With **`site_url`**

All return blank page (500 internal error)
Can help me, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a standard *wp-config.php* file, `ABSPATH` should be defined.  This means you should be able to use:

```
include_once(ABSPATH . 'includes/db_connect.php');
```

Read more in [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356467/3518452).

Comment: yeah.. easy enuff.. this should work :)